# Clickable ImageView inside Button

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-button

Whenever I set the ImageView to clickable it's crashing. Is it not possible to have a clickable ImageView inside a button or am just doing it wrong? I already set the image to be clickable.

** **EDITED** **

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

btPlumbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            View layoutPlumber = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_plumber, null);
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(layoutPlumber);

            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) layoutPlumber.getParent());
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(
                    (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 400, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())
            );

            ImageView imgPTap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_pTap);

            imgPTap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //
                }
            });

            bottomSheetDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

**Here's the error:**

```
 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                     at com.fixitph.client.HomeActivity$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:189)
                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19900)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:975)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

**XML file**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_pTap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plumber_64dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDITED WITH XML**

Comment: `imgPTab` or `btPlumbers` is `null`. I don't know which one is `ImageView`

Comment: imgPTab is the ImageView @StefanGolubović

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: [@Blue Collar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9419938/blue-collar) how (or where) did you initialize `imgPTab`?

Comment: it is inside onCreate @StefanGolubović

Comment: [@Blue Collar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9419938/blue-collar) paste that code or figure out (debug) why's `imgPTab` `null`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a duplicate of this but that post is complicated for me, I'm only starting to learn @SantanuSur

Comment: Why there is a clicklistener inside another clicklistener?

Comment: Is it not allowed? What I'm trying to achieve is, after clicking a button, a bottom sheet will pull up with clickable images. @SabaJafarzadeh

Comment: as said by @StefanGolubović there is every chance here that imgPTap is null. can you paste a code of how you are initialising imgPTap?

Comment: @AADProgramming edited my post. I tried initializing ImageView inside the button, still the same thing, it was initialized outside the button but inside onCreate before.

Comment: Hi @SantanuSur I think I sort of understand that post but if you look at my code I have initialized my ImageView, I still don't understand why I'm getting the same issue

Comment: then post your activity xml code please @BlueCollar

Comment: Hi @SantanuSur I edited my post with the XML code

Comment: i said post your `activity_home` xml code

Comment: i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either *btPlumbers* or *imgPtap* is null. Try assigning them a value before calling `setOnClickListener()`

You can do it this way:

```
btPlumbers = findViewById(R.id.<your_view_id>);
imgPtap = findViewById(R.id.<your_view_id>);
```

Comment: Yes I have both initialized inside onCreate, same location of the button (btPlumbers)

Comment: @BlueCollar, check again the code above is your on create and btPlumbers is definitely not initialized.

Comment: Hi @JoelLibby I tried initializing it inside both onCreate but not inside Button and inside Button gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  ImageView imgPTap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_pTap);
```

try this in your activity .

```
  ImageView imgPTap = (ImageView) layoutPlumber.findViewById(R.id.imageview_pTap);
```

( **still i flag this question as duplicate** )